# Unknown Error when deploying site to netlify from codesandbox

Tags: vue.js, netlify, codesandbox

When attempting to deploy my portfolio from CodeSandbox to netlify, it shows me an error: 
'**An unknown error occurred when deploying your site**'


The sandbox having issues is: https://codesandbox.io/embed/mycoal-t90x3

Furthermore, when observing the console, this is what shows:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://netlify.deploy.codesandbox.io/site/t90x3/deploys?siteId=5915a846-8947-4bbd-9a6a-ec0765deea4e&dist=dist&buildCommand=build' from origin 'https://codesandbox.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I have another website made for a client that I have been able to successfully deploy with no issues that has a similar markup.
**https://codesandbox.io/s/sorbet10-e8k0s**
and I have had no issues in deploying this.

I expected the website to deploy with no issues, and have reviewed dependencies to ensure working versions and no concomitant issues between them, but still no luck.